# Searching for customers in other table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've 2 tables:

```
CUSTOMERS
id    company    frontname

PROJECT 
id    customer_id
```

What I want to do is searching for a customer, and return an project. Who can help me with this subject?

Comment: suggest you post an attempt

Comment: `Who can help me with this subject?` - pls post the queries you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all projects of a customer when you join the 2 tables and add a `where`  condition

```
select p.*
from project p
inner join customer c on c.id = p.customer_id
where c.frontname = 'customer name'
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM PROJECT WHERE customer_id = yourvalue`

or if you need to query values from the customer table simply do a join.

```
SELECT * FROM Project p 
JOIN CUSTOMER c on P.customer_id = c.id
WHERE c.company = 'CompanyName'
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!